# Why is Neo4j(Client) running out of memory?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am creating 1 million nodes. I had to create these in smaller batches to avoid running out of memory. Now I am trying to delete the existing nodes but again I am getting an out of memory exception. I should really be able to delete this level of data without running out of memory and without having to code around this limit. Am I doing something wrong here?

I know I could increase the Java heap size, but I feel that would just be deferring the real problem to a later point in time when I have much more data to create/delete.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Neo4jClient;

    namespace Neo4JWontDelete
    {
        class Program
        {
            private const int MaximumNumberOfWordsToCreate = 1000*1000;
            private const int BatchSize = 5 * 1000;

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://neo4j:Xxxxxx1@localhost:7474/db/data"));
                client.Connect();

                Console.WriteLine("Starting with a clean database");
                DeleteAllObjects(client);

                Console.WriteLine("Creating data");
                int currentWordNumber = 1;
                while (currentWordNumber < MaximumNumberOfWordsToCreate)
                {
                    int numberOfWordsToCreate = MaximumNumberOfWordsToCreate - currentWordNumber;
                    if (numberOfWordsToCreate > BatchSize)
                        numberOfWordsToCreate = BatchSize;
                    var words = Enumerable.Range(currentWordNumber, BatchSize).Select(x => new Word {Value = x.ToString()});
                    client.Cypher
                        .Create("(w:Word {words})")
                        .WithParam("words", words)
                        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
                    currentWordNumber += numberOfWordsToCreate;
                    Console.WriteLine(currentWordNumber - 1);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Deleting data");
                DeleteAllObjects(client);
            }

            private static void DeleteAllObjects(GraphClient client)
            {
                client.Cypher
                    .Match("(w :Word)")
                    .Delete("w")
                    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
            }
    }

    class Word
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why set BatchSize and MaximumNumberOfWordsToCreate to the result of multiplication, and not just 1000000 and 5000?

Comment: Hi Peter, Just something I noticed - do you want a clean DB or just to remove the 'words'? Clean db would be `.Match("n").OptionalMatch("n-[r]-()").Delete(n,r).ExecuteWithoutResults()`

Answer (score 0):

This problem only seems to exist in the community edition. The 30 day trial of the enterprise edition works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do your words have relationships?

Otherwise you can batch it simply too.

`MATCH (w:Word) with w limit 500000 delete w`

With relationships you'd do

`MATCH (w:Word) with w limit 50000 optional match (w)-[r]-() delete w,r`